# Why does or rather how does object.__new__ work differently in these two cases

Tags: python, object, constructor

Python version: "'2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) \n[GCC 4.6.3]'"

I have this:

```
>>> class testclass1(object):
    ...     pass
    ... 

>>> class testclass2(object):
    ...     def __init__(self,param):
    ...             pass
    ... 

>>> a = object.__new__(testclass1, 56)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters

>>> b = object.__new__(testclass2, 56)

>>> b
    <__main__.testclass2 object at 0x276a5d0>
```

Some more fun! Compare with results of testclass1 above.

```
>>> class testclass3(object):
    ...     def __init__(self):
    ...             pass
    ... 

>>> c = object.__new__(testclass3, 56)

>>> c
    <__main__.testclass3 object at 0x276a790>

>>> c1 = object.__new__(testclass3)

>>> c1
    <__main__.testclass3 object at 0x276a810>
```

My question is **how does** (not why does) `object__new__` behave differently in these two cases?
Also notice the error is kind of misleading in the first case because in the second case `object.__new__` does end up taking an argument!.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? I cannot repeat your first error message; what I get instead in both 2.7 and 3.3 is `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`, which is less misleading because it doesn't claim anything about `__new__`, only about the constructor.

Comment: @user4815162342 I am on 2.7 and can reliably repro the error.

Comment: Ah, they changed it between 2.7.3 and 2.7.4, probably to reflect a similar change in 3.x sources.

Comment: the answers given below do not answer why : 
1. it should be object.__init__ takes no parameters instead of object.__new__ takes no parameter (testclass1)
2. why no error is raised for testclass3 ? (as it takes no arguments other than self)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `object.__new__` and `object.__init__` go through a carefully constructed maze of conditions that allow excess arguments in some cases, raise an error in others, and raise a warning in a very specific one. [The code that implements the checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62fa613f6a6e872723505ee9d56242c31a654a9d/Objects/typeobject.c#L4444) is easy enough to follow, but the reasoning behind it would likely remain inscrutable without [this elucidating comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62fa613f6a6e872723505ee9d56242c31a654a9d/Objects/typeobject.c#L4368):

> You may wonder why `object.__new__()` only complains about arguments
> when `object.__init__()` is not overridden, and vice versa.
>
> Consider the use cases:
>
> 1. When neither is overridden, we want to hear complaints about excess (i.e., any) arguments, since their presence could indicate there's a
>    bug.
> 2. When defining an Immutable type, we are likely to override only `__new__()`, since `__init__()` is called too late to initialize an
>    Immutable object.  Since `__new__()` defines the signature for the
>    type, it would be a pain to have to override `__init__()` just to stop
>    it from complaining about excess arguments.
> 3. When defining a Mutable type, we are likely to override only `__init__()`.  So here the converse reasoning applies: we don't want
>    to have to override `__new__()` just to stop it from complaining.
> 4. When `__init__()` is overridden, and the subclass `__init__()` calls `object.__init__()`, the latter should complain about excess
>    arguments; ditto for `__new__()`.
>
> Use cases 2 and 3 make it unattractive to unconditionally check for
> excess arguments.  The best solution that addresses all four use cases
> is as follows: `__init__()` complains about excess arguments unless
> `__new__()` is overridden and `__init__()` is not overridden (IOW, if
> `__init__()` is overridden or `__new__()` is not overridden);
> symmetrically, `__new__()` complains about excess arguments unless
> `__init__()` is overridden and `__new__()` is not overridden (IOW, if
> `__new__()` is overridden or `__init__()` is not overridden).
>
> However, for backwards compatibility, this breaks too much code.
> Therefore, in 2.6, we'll *warn* about excess arguments when both
> methods are overridden; for all other cases we'll use the above rules.

Answer (score 3):

The **class** that you are creating has its member `__init__()` is called by `new()` to handle any creation parameters but in the fist case you have no `__init__` so can not pass any parameters.

Comment: Right. I was more interested in how does this happen and not why does this happen.

Comment: The `object.new()` code checks for an init method and raises an error if it is not possible to call it with the supplied parameters

Comment: Interestingly, both `object.__new__` and `object.__init__` go through a carefully constructed maze of conditions that allow excess arguments in some cases, raise an error in others, and raise a warning in a specific one. It would be quite hard to understand without [this elucidating comment](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/44ed0cd3dc6d/Objects/typeobject.c#l2818) in the code.

Comment: @user4815162342 If you make your comment as an answer I would be inclined to accept that as the answer to my question.

Comment: @abc I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `__new__` static method takes a class as its first argument. The other arguments will be passed into that class's `__init__` method. Since your class has no `__init__` method, `__new__` won't accept the other arguments.

Take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) for more info.

As for the "how", it's implemented in C (`Objects/typeobject.c`), but you could perform that same check with pure Python:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

    if not hasattr(cls, '__init__') and (args or kwargs):
        raise TypeError("object.__init__() takes no parameters")

    ...
```

Comment: Right. I was more interested in how does this happen and not why does this happen.

Comment: @abc: I'm not really sure what you mean by "how". It's implemented in C.

Comment: There is a bug in the code. `not` has higher precedence than `and` and it is not so much the args to `__new__` that matter its the args to `__init__` that lead ( or do not lead to the error).

Comment: @abc: Well, yeah. The error is thrown only if you supply extra arguments to `__new__` and the class has no `__init__` method. Like I said, if you're interested in the actual implementation, look at the C source.