# Why does object.__new__ work differently in these three cases

Tags: python, object, types, constructor

from question [Why does or rather how does object.__new__ work differently in these two cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680901/why-does-or-rather-how-does-object-new-work-differently-in-these-two-cases)

the author wasn't interested in the why, but rather in the how.

I would very much want to understand why, particularly :

1. why isn't `object.__init__` takes no parameters printed instead of `object.__new__ (in testclass1)`
2. why no error is raised for testclass3 ? (as it takes no arguments other than self)

code

```
>>> class testclass1(object):
    ...     pass
    ... 

>>> class testclass2(object):
    ...     def __init__(self,param):
    ...             pass
    ... 

>>> a = object.__new__(testclass1, 56)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters

>>> b = object.__new__(testclass2, 56)

>>> b
    <__main__.testclass2 object at 0x276a5d0>

>>> class testclass3(object):
    ...     def __init__(self):
    ...             pass
    ... 

>>> c = object.__new__(testclass3, 56)

>>> c
    <__main__.testclass3 object at 0x276a790>

>>> c1 = object.__new__(testclass3)

>>> c1
    <__main__.testclass3 object at 0x276a810>
```

Comment: Did you read [this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/44ed0cd3dc6d/Objects/typeobject.c#l2818) comment on the python sources? They decided to *not* raise an error in some circumstances to allow defining only one of `__init__` or `__new__`. Otherwise you'd always have to redefined them, even if they were no-ops.

Comment: I don't understand that :s I defined only __init__, it takes no arguments (other than self obviously), I'm passing in an argument to __new__, why doesn't it raise an error ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using an older Python version; the error message has since been updated:

```
>>> object.__new__(testclass1, 56)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Python will only complain about `__init__` not supporting arguments if neither `__new__` nor `__init__` have been overridden; e.g. when you inherit both from `object`. `testclass1` fits that case, `testclass3` does not because it has an `__init__` method.

This is to support implementing immutable types that don't have a use for `__init__` (which would be inherited from `object` in that case), *and* mutable types, where `__new__` should not care about what arguments `__init__` expects (which usually would be *more* arguments).

See [issue 1683368](http://bugs.python.org/issue1683368) where Guido van Rossum explains his motivations for this.

The [`typeobject.c` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/372abcca25fc/Objects/typeobject.c#l2820) has this to say:

> You may wonder why `object.__new__()` only complains about arguments
>   when `object.__init__()` is not overridden, and vice versa.
>
> Consider the use cases:
>
> 1. When neither is overridden, we want to hear complaints about
>        excess (i.e., any) arguments, since their presence could
>        indicate there's a bug.
> 2. When defining an Immutable type, we are likely to override only
>        `__new__()`, since `__init__()` is called too late to initialize an
>        Immutable object.  Since `__new__()` defines the signature for the
>        type, it would be a pain to have to override `__init__()` just to
>        stop it from complaining about excess arguments.
> 3. When defining a Mutable type, we are likely to override only
>        `__init__()`.  So here the converse reasoning applies: we don't
>        want to have to override `__new__()` just to stop it from
>        complaining.
> 4. When `__init__()` is overridden, and the subclass `__init__()` calls
>        `object.__init__()`, the latter should complain about excess
>        arguments; ditto for `__new__()`.
>
> Use cases 2 and 3 make it unattractive to unconditionally check for
>   excess arguments.  The best solution that addresses all four use 
>   cases is as follows: `__init__()` complains about excess arguments 
>   unless `__new__()` is overridden and `__init__()` is not overridden 
>   (IOW, if `__init__()` is overridden or `__new__()` is not overridden); 
>   symmetrically, `__new__()` complains about excess arguments unless 
>   `__init__()` is overridden and `__new__()` is not overridden
>   (IOW, if `__new__()` is overridden or `__init__()` is not overridden).
>
> However, for backwards compatibility, this breaks too much code. 
>   Therefore, in 2.6, we'll *warn* about excess arguments when both 
>   methods are overridden; for all other cases we'll use the above 
>   rules.

Note that the `.__init__()` method **itself** will still complain! When you create an instance, both `__new__` and `__init__` are called; your code only calls `__new__` directly and does *not* invoke `__init__`! Creating an instance of `testclass1` and `testclass3` both fails if you pass in arguments:

```
>>> testclass1(56)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
>>> testclass3(56)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

The only difference is that for `testclass1` it is the default methods for `object()` that complain instead a specific error for the custom `__init__`.