# Subclassing builtin types -- Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have code that looks like the following:

```
class Token(object):
    '''
    Resulting from parse
    '''
    def __new__(cls,text,begin,end,*args,**kargs):
        self = super(Token,cls).__new__(cls,*args,**kargs)
        return self

    def __init__(self,text,begin,end,*args,**kargs):
        super(Token,self).__init__(*args,**kargs)
        self.text = text
        self.begin = begin
        self.end = end

class List(Token,list):
    pass

class Str(Token,str):
    pass

class Int(Token,int):
    pass

s = Str('hey there',0,3,'hey there'[0:3])
print(s)

x = Int('55 12',0,2,'55 12'[0:2])
print(x)
```

Basically what I want to do is to easily create types that are just normal Python types, but with some extra information to them.

Python 2 seems to be OK with the above code, but Python 3 complains

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 71, in <module>
    s = Str('',1,2,'hey')
  File "simple.py", line 12, in __init__
    super(Token,self).__init__(*args,**kargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I think the interpreters would be happy if I did something like

```
class List(list):
    def __init__(self,text,begin,end,*args,**kargs):
        list.__init__(*args,**kargs)
```

But this would mean I would have to repeat something similar for every new class I want to make... and I would rather stay relatively DRY...

Is there a 'proper' way I should handle this situation so that both Python 2 and Python 3 are happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use exception handling here:

```
def __init__(self,text,begin,end,*args,**kargs):
    try:
        super(Token,self).__init__(*args,**kargs)
    except TypeError:
        # Python 3 and the mixed in type is immutable.
        # Ignoring this is fine, `__new__` took care of this.
        pass
    self.text = text
    self.begin = begin
    self.end = end
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great! However, I am a bit confused... Even if the mixed in type is immutable, shouldn't the dummy `__init__` take into account the extra arguments? Why is there a TypeError?

Comment: @math4tots: The mutable types have a `__init__` method, the immutable types don't. So `list.__init__` exists, `unicode.__init__` doesn't. Which means that for immutable types, `object.__init__` is called. And the rules for what `object.__init__` accepts have changed between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: See [Why does object.\_\_new\_\_ work differently in these three cases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19277399) for the nitty gritty details there.

Comment: Thank you so much! That link you referred me to really cleared things up for me about some fundamental misunderstandngs I've had about `__new__` and `__init__`

Comment: @math4tots: Glad to have been of help twice today, then! :-)