# Why does object.__new__ with arguments work fine in Python 2.x and not in Python 3.3+?

Tags: python, python-3.3, python-2.x

Why does the following code work fine in Python 2.x and not in Python 3.3+:

```
class TestA(object):
    def __new__(cls, e):
        return super(TestA, cls).__new__(TestB, e)

class TestB(TestA):
    def __init__(self, e):
        print(self, e)

TestA(1)
```

Python 2.7.6 output:

```
(<__main__.TestB object at 0x7f6303378ad0>, 1)
```

Python 3.1.5 output:

```
__main__:3: DeprecationWarning: object.__new__() takes no parameters
<__main__.TestB object at 0x7f2f69db8f10> 1
```

Python 3.2.3 and 3.2.5 output:

```
<__main__.TestB object at 0xcda690> 1
```

Python 3.3.5 and 3.4.1 output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __new__
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: Related: [Why does object.\_\_new\_\_ work differently in these three cases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19277399)

Comment: It's interpretator output, first print, second object. If run as program will one line. Fixed.

Comment: Are you sure ? This code work on Python 2.7.4 and Python 3.2.3.

Comment: For 3.2.3 work fine, updated post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`object.__new__` has always ignored extra arguments, and has issued a `DeprecationWarning` at least since Python 2.6.

The reason why you aren't seeing the `DeprecationWarning` in 2.7 and 3.2 is that since 2.7 and 3.2 `DeprecationWarning` has been [suppressed by default](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/2.7.html#changes-to-the-handling-of-deprecation-warnings); if you use `python -Wd` or `PYTHONWARNINGS=default` then you will see the warning.

In Python 3.3 the `DeprecationWarning` was converted to an error.

The correct way to write your code (in any version of Python) is to swallow the extra argument in `TestA.__new__`:

```
class TestA(object):
    def __new__(cls, e):
        return super(TestA, cls).__new__(TestB)
```

Since `TestB` is derived from `TestA`, the extra argument [will be passed to `TestB.__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

Comment: Note that the Python documentation is silent about what to do with the extra arguments in an implementation of `__new__()`. It just states that these are the arguments "passed to the object constructor expression (the call to the class)", but it does not mention the DeprecationWarning or error described in the answer above (which I think is correct).

Answer (score 1):

You can move the __init__ function to TestA like so:

```
class TestA(object):
    def __new__(cls, e):
        return super(TestA, cls).__new__(TestA)

    def __init__(self, e):
        print(self, e)

TestA(1)
```

Notice how TestB is not required.

Notice how the 'e' parameter is omitted from the call to object.__new__.
The new function of object class only takes a class as parameter and any additional parameters in the overloaded __new__ function (in this case that of class TestA) is automatically passed to the constructor function (__init__) of the classed passed to object.__new__ (which in this case is also TestA).