# Python subclassing a class with custom __new__

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, subclassing

There's a class (not created by me, from a 3rd party library) that has no `__init__` declared (other than `object`'s `__init__`), and this is its `__new__`:

```
def __new__(cls, uid):
    self = super().__new__(cls, uid)
    self._info = get_info_from_uid(uid)
    return self
```

I can't see why didn't they just use `__init__` here, but they didn't.

Now I'd like to subclass this and give it an additional attribute; before I checked the source-code of the class (only the documentation), I thought it's just using `__init__` like others, so here's what I did:

```
class MyClass(TheirClass):
    def __init__(self, uid, my_stuff=()):
        super().__init__(uid)
        self.my_stuff = my_stuff
```

Apparently this raised a TypeError from `object.__init__()` not taking parameteres.
How should I subclass such class with `__new__`? 
Do I just override the `__new__` method to?

Comment: The `__new__` method, as posted, will not work unless the class inherits from something other than `object` itself; `object.__new__` doesn't take arguments in this case. I'd expect it to read `self = super().__new__(cls)`.

Comment: Also, surely they'd use `get_info_from_uid(uid)` (not `self.uid`) there?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah it does inherit from few other classes too, but they don't have `__init__` declared either. And yeah sorry about the `self.uid`, that was my typo when trying to create my own class, forgot it there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the original project stuck with `__new__` and using both `__init__` and `__new__` together in sub-classes [can get very tricky indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277399/why-does-object-new-work-differently-in-these-three-cases), you'll have to use `__new__` in subclasses as well:

```
class MyClass(TheirClass):
    def __new__(cls, uid, my_stuff=()):
        self = super().__new__(cls, uid)
        self.my_stuff = my_stuff
        return self
```

Perhaps the original author felt that the type should be treated as an immutable.

You can still use `__init__` if you insist, but you'll have to specify a `__new__` method *anyway* to account for the extra argument your `__init__` now takes:

```
class MyClass(TheirClass):
    def __new__(cls, uid, *args):
        # ignore the extra arguments
        return super().__new__(cls, uid)

    def __init__(self, uid, my_stuff=()):
        self.my_stuff = my_stuff
```

Comment: "Perhaps the original author felt that the type should be treated as an immutable.", can you enlighten me a little on this? How's the `__new__` related to making an object immutable? Edit: Yeah thanks, I'll just override the `__new__` in my subclass! :)

Comment: This works well for my application, and I have defined `__repr__()` that includes printing the added variable. This works as well, but if I inspect with `getmembers` (`from inspect import getmembers`), I get an error that there is no member with the new variable (`AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no 'my_stuff' member`).