# I don't understand why the result is "B's __new__() invoked A's __init__() invoked A's __new__() invoked"

Tags: python, oop

```
class A:
    def __new__(self):
        self.__init__(self)
        print("A's __new__() invoked") #print if called

    def __init__(self):
        print("A's __init__() invoked") #print if called

class B(A):
    def __new__(self):
        print("B's __new__() invoked") #print if called

    def __init__(self):
        print("B's __init__() invoked") #print if called

def main():
    b = B() #create an object of B
    a = A() #create an object of A

main()
```

why the result is "B's **new**() invoked A's **init**() invoked A's **new**() invoked?I wonder why B's **init** method is not called.

Comment: Because you overrode `B.__new__` and didn't call `__init__`. Also, `__new__` should not take a `self` argument because there is no `self` object; it's `__new__`'s job to create it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236516/python-subclassing-a-class-with-custom-new

Comment: `__new__` is still given the class invoking it as an argument; whether you call it `self` or `cls` or anything else is immaterial (though using something that doesn't suggest a class goes against convention).

Comment: Most relevant here, though, is the fact that neither `A.__new__` nor `B.__new__` returns an instance of their class, so neither invokes `__init__` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For a class `Foo`, `Foo.__init__` is only invoked automatically by `Foo()` if `Foo.__new__` returns an instance of `Foo`. `B.__new__` returns `None`, so `B.__init__` does not get called.

`A.__init__` is only called because it is explicitly called by `A.__new__`, though not in a meaningful way because it is passed the class `A` itself, not an instance of `A`.

`Foo()` invokes `type(Foo).__call__(Foo)`, and you can imagine that method being defined somewhat like

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        cls.__init__(obj)
    return obj
```

---

If you define `__new__`, keep in mind the following:

1. `__new__` is a static method (though special cased by Python so that you don't need the `@staticmethod` decoration) that receives a *class* as its first argument, so the name should of the parameter should reflect that.
2. For most use cases, the purpose of `__new__` is to call `super().__new__` to get an instance of the class, possibly doing some
   post-processing of the new object before returning it.
3. As `__init__` will be called automatically on the new instance (assuming it is of the correct type), `__new__` should not call `__init__` itself.

Comment: Nice answer! The thing about `__call__` makes sense, do you have a link for the actual implementation of it?

Comment: I feel like I've seen this Python equivalent *somewhere*, but I can't recall where. (It's quite possible I made this up myself.) The actual definition of `__call__` is buried in the C implementation (in `typeobject.c`, I think), but not in a way that makes it obvious (to me, anyway) what is going on.